# How to calibrate the size and speed of 3d objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

everyone

I am just starting with a new project in VR and have some problems.

I want to simulate a simple 3D-Ball like the real one in real world.

I am using OptiTrack to register my camera( 3d glasses) and Middle VR(free edition) to realize the 3D effect in 3D room. And also Unity for 3D models and programming with C#.

***My Problem:***

I have a real plastic ball and use it to compare with that 3D-Ball. If i go to the real ball in (real world) it will be bigger and if i go away from it, it will be smaller visually.

The 3d ball has the same diameter as the real one and stand at the same position. But if i go to ihm with 3d glasses it will be (quicker) bigger than the one in real world and if i go away from it, it will quick smaller than the real one...

Can anyone explain to me, how to solve the problem, what should i do. I need your help.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Carvin.

Answer (score 1):

Get the size right inside unity. 1 unit in unity is 1 meter in real life.
Also play with the field of view of your maincamera in unity to get the desired result